# How to access the properties from data being parsed by a parent class?

Tags: javascript

I created a base class that parses a json file:

```
const fs = require("fs");

class DataRepository {
  constructor() {
    this.filename = "cales_data.json";
    try {
      fs.accessSync(this.filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("data does not exist");
    }
  }

  async getAll() {
    // Open the file called this.filename
    return JSON.parse(
      await fs.promises.readFile(this.filename, {
        encoding: "utf-8",
      })
    );
  }

  async getOneBy(filters) {
    const records = await this.getAll();

    for (let record of records) {
      let found = true;

      for (let key in filters) {
        if (record[key] !== filters[key]) {
          found = false;
        }
      }

      if (found) {
        return record;
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = DataRepository;
```

I don't care for its methods at this point. I just want to be able to access the contents of `this.filename = "cales_data.json";`

Something like this perhaps:

```
const DataRepository = require("./repositories/data");

class Address extends DataRepository {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.Address = DataRepository.Address;
    this.Latitude = DataRepository.Latitude;
    this.Longitude = DataRepository.Longitude;
  }
}

module.exports = Address;
```

but obviously the above gives me undefined. Is it possible to access those properties inside that JSON file in that base class this way? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: no. "This" can never result to anything than a value on the class memory stack. You have to handle this different:-)

Comment: could I trouble you for a suggestion. A more robust answer? For example, I tried using the data as a csv file, but perhaps the way I was parsing it was messing me up. Would you recommend working with it as a csv file? Feel free to post your reply as part of your answer.